# java script code to handle internet explorer "metro mode" to open each link in divided screen

Tags: javascript

I want to write java script code for Internet Explorer (Metro mode) so that when I click on any link of the applications it will open that link ub half screen of IE app like in this image:

[image: expected]

I was using "window.open", and it is opening links in new window for all browsers but in the case of internet explorer Metro mode it is opening a new tab.
Like this:

[image: actual]

Comment: Do you know upfront whether IE even allows that, or is that a part of the question?

Comment: Yes IE allows it but don,t know how to do that through coding.